# django filter format for date

Tags: django, date, format

year_id (2004 etc) is a dropdown box on the template.  The users selects a year and this is retrieved as year_id in the view.  I need to select publications based on year from a field called grantstartdt which is in the format 2008-01-01.  The error is:

int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Year'

```
year_id = request.GET['year_id']  
yr = get_object_or_404(Year, pk=year_id) 
projectyr=Researchproject.objects.exclude(activeyesno = 2).filter(grantstartdt__year=yr)
```

Thank you for any assistance!

Comment: Is `grantstartdt` a `CharField` or what? Can you show us its definition? (Remember, you can edit your question to add more information)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing `year_id` instead of `yr` in that `filter()` call:

```
projectyr=Researchproject.objects.exclude(activeyesno = 2).filter(grantstartdt__year=year_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you are referring to the year object instead of the actual year. Assuming your Year model has a integer field called **xyz**. Your code should look like..

```
year_id = request.GET['year_id']  
yr = get_object_or_404(Year, pk=year_id) 
projectyr=Researchproject.objects.exclude(activeyesno = 2).filter(grantstartdt__year=yr.xyz)
```